# TabView - PageTabView()

Tags: swiftui

I am working on TabView with a bunch of items and they are kind of laggy. I couldn't find LazyTabView on the internet, so is there an alternative way to load smoothly. Thank you. My code is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(1..<1001, id: \.self) { i in
                Text("Row \(i)")
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static_var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the total number of the items?

Answer (score 2):

you could try something different, like this approach using a `ScrollView` and `LazyHGrid`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geom in
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHGrid(rows: [GridItem(.flexible())]) {
                    ForEach(1..<1001, id: \.self) { i in
                        Text("Row \(i)").frame(width: geom.size.width)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ScrollView and TabView are the same?

Comment: This approach is new to me. Thanks for sharing @workingdog. It looks like there is no direct implementation for LazyTabView.  Turns out, TabView(selection: ) with long ForEach would be impossible to do right now.